# Getting the highest number in ['76 125 94 95 122 96 126 123 124 87']?

Tags: python, string, list

Given a single-element `list` such as:

```
['76 125 94 95 122 96 126 123 124 87']
```

I'm looking to get out the highest number (as an `int`) from the string. Rather than extract the zeroth element of the list, then split into a new list, then convert each element of this new list to ints, and then finally get the `max()`, is there a one (or two) liner that can do the same things?

Comment: What you describe only takes one or two lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Rather than extract the zeroth element of the list, then split into a new list, then convert each element of this new list to ints, and then finally get the max(), is there a one (or two) liner that can do the same things?

You can do all of those in a single line, like this

```
>>> max(map(int, data[0].split()))
126
```

Instead of using `map` (which returns a `list` in Python 2), we can simply use a generator expression, which will produce values on-demand.

```
>>> max(int(item) for item in data[0].split())
126
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, you can actually do it without involving the highlighted operations in your rather interesting request

> Rather than **extract the zeroth element** of the list, then **split into a**
>   **new list**, then **convert each element of this new list to ints**, and then
>   finally get the max(), is there a one (or two) liner that can do the
>   same things?

by using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). The end result is rather contriving and should not be encouraged over what @thefourtheye proposed.

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = ['76 125 94 95 122 96 126 123 124 87']
>>> max(ast.literal_eval(''.join(data).replace(' ',',')))
126
```